# Same code doesn't work in different environments

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery code in my [production](http://mitpachat.com/c/73/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%AA) and [test](http://mitpachattest19.com.yew.arvixe.com/c/53/%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA) env

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).find('div.description:contains("חדש")').each(function() {
        $(this).closest(".item-box").find(".picture a").addClass("SaleProduct");;
        $('div.description:contains("מבצע")').each(function() {
            $(this).closest(".item-box").find(".picture a").addClass("NewProduct");
        });
    });
});​
```

but some how the same code dosen't work is the prod env. i am certain that the jQuery is being called 
but i cant figure whay it doesn't work .

Comment: What does the JS console say?

Comment: well if the code you shown is the exactly the same in both environment then the problem must lie outside of the code you have shown

Comment: *"dosen't work is the prod env"* means what exactly? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: try with apache encoding config

Comment: My dev-tools (Chromium 18) show that your css (`1237.css.aspx`) is failing to load, with a `404`; but I'm not sure that should be a problem or not.

Comment: failed to load http://www.fontface.co.il/fonts/1237.css.aspx

Answer (score 0):

a. This could be related to encoding of the file. Verify the file on testing and production are both of the same time encoding. You can use something like Notepad++ to resave the file in the expected encoding.

b. Are you using firefox? Get firebug, and navigate to the production site. Use the inspector and search for the text you are looking for. Verify it is actually there.

c. Break apart the javascript and then use the firebug debugger to step through the javascript call to see where it fails:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var divs = $(this).find('div.description:contains("חדש")');
   divs.each(function(){
    var clostedItemBox = $(this).closest(".item-box");
    var picture = clostedItemBox.find(".picture a");
    picture.addClass("SaleProduct");;
   $('div.description:contains("מבצע")').each(function(){
    $(this).closest(".item-box").find(".picture a").addClass("NewProduct");
  });
});

});
```

Put break points on each line and see where it fails on you.